# Not able to individually cross items off the list

Tags: javascript, dom

i have been trying to build a To Do list app and when i try to click anywhere on the list always the first item gets crossed off the list and not the one that was clicked.
and
what's the best way to apply CSS styles that are in the CSS code below?
i have posted the code below.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

const textBox = document.querySelector('#textBox');
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
const data = document.querySelector('.data');
const close = document.querySelector('.close');

const li = document.querySelector('LI');

list.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target ) {
    li.classList.add('task');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <div class="data">
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Meet Denise<span class="close"></span></li>
      <li><span class="check"></span>Grocery</li>
      <li>Book Appointment</li>
      <li>Watch GOT</li>
      <li>Book Flight</li>
      <li>Buy Ipad</li>
      <li>Pick up kids</li>
      <li>Complete Homework</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: *"...and what's the best way to apply CSS styles that are in the CSS code below?"* Your post has HTML and JavaScript, but it is  entirely lacking any CSS whatsoever.

Comment: I tried to include CSS but stackoverflow won't let me post it , because it had too much code (talking about the whole post) it it.

Comment: No worries. My point is, edit the post so the reader doesn't expect CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
const li = document.querySelector('LI');
```

This line selects the first occurence of `li` tag in the whole document.

You are alreday getting the event `e` in addEventListener handler and checking for the target. Change your code to add class to `e.target`:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

list.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target) {
    e.target.classList.add('task')
  }
})
```

```css
.task {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>To Do</h1>
  <div class="data">
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Meet Denise</li>
      <li>Grocery</li>
      <li>Book Appointment</li>
      <li>Watch GOT</li>
      <li>Book Flight</li>
      <li>Buy Ipad</li>
      <li>Pick up kids</li>
      <li>Complete Homework</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Also you can remove the selectors which are not being used.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following demo adds, checks, unchecks, deletes single and multiple tasks, and sets specific tasks as higher priority.

```
/**
* Render predefined tags in and around the given list tag (<ol> or <ul>), 
* and its children <li>. Also, class attributes are assigned throughout 
* the tags (new and old), and the list is registered to the "click"    
* event. When triggered by event the event handler function toDo() is
* called. All this is done in order to convert the static list into a 
* dynamic and interactive ToDo list. 
**
* @param  {String} selector - A CSS selector string of a pre-existing 
*                             <ul> or <ol>.
**
* function initList(selector) {...
```

A fully functional example can be reviewed in the ***Demo*** section. Here is a *before* and *after* example of `initList()` results:

**Before**

```
<ul class='list'>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Gamma</li>
  <li>Delta</li>
</ul>
```

**After**

```
<header class='title'>
  <h1>To Do</h1> <a href='#/' id='all'>Remove Selected Tasks <b>❎</b></a>
</header>
<ul class='list'>
  <li><b class='status open'></b>Alpha<b class='status close'>❎</b></li>
  <li><b class='status open'></b>Beta<b class='status close'>❎</b></li>
  <li><b class='status open'></b>Gamma<b class='status close'>❎</b></li>
  <li><b class='status open'></b>Delta<b class='status close'>❎</b></li>
</ul>
<footer class='aux'>
  <b class='flag open'></b> <input id='text'> 
  <input id='add' type='button' value='Add'>
</footer>
```

---

- There are two more tags registered to the "click" event: `a#all` and `footer.aux`
- The event handlers:

  - `a#all`: `function allSel(event)` removes selected tasks (`li.task.selected`)
  - `footer.aux`: `function addTask(event)` adds new tasks to the list and optionally assign any task to a higher priority.
  - `ul#list`: `function toDo(event)` sets up the list to un/check, and delete tasks one-by-one.

---

#### References

- [**`.insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [**`.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [**`for...of` Loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [**`.forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [**`event.currentTarget`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- [**`event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [**`.matches()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [**Event Delegation**](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

---

#### Demo

**Brief Directions**

Remove All Selected Tasks ❎
 OR ✅ Normal Priority                    ❎
 OR ☑️ High Priority                         ❎
                     <kbd>Text of new task</kbd>                    <kbd>Add</kbd>

- **Check/Uncheck a task** in the list, click the icons at the beginning of each task: ,✅,,☑️
- **Remove a task** from the list click the icons at the end of each task: ❎
- **Remove multiple tasks** from the list:

  1. Select the tasks by clicking the text of each: *Normal Priority, High Priority*
  2. Then click the button-link in the header: *Remove All Selected Tasks* ❎
- **Add a task** to the list:

  1. Enter text of task in the following input:                     <kbd>Text of new task</kbd>
  2. Click the following (the button is actually green): <kbd>Add</kbd>
- **Add a high priority task** to the top of the list:

  1. Check the following: from  to ☑️
  2. Enter text of task in the following input:                     <kbd>Text of new task</kbd>
  3. Click the following (the button is actually green): <kbd>Add</kbd>

---

```js
function initList(selector) {
  const list = document.querySelector(selector);
  const head = `
  <header class='title'><h1>To Do</h1>
    <a href='#/' id='all'>Remove Selected Tasks <b>❎</b></a>
  </header>`;
  const foot = `
  <footer class='aux'><b class='flag open'></b>
    <input id='text'><input id='add' type='button' value='Add'>
  </footer>`;
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', head);
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', foot);

  const items = list.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let item of items) {
    const open = `<b class='status open'></b> `;
    const close = ` <b class='status close'>❎</b>`;
    item.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', open);
    item.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', close);
    item.classList.add('task');
  }
  list.addEventListener('click', toDo);
}

initList('#list');

const all = document.querySelector('#all');
const aux = document.querySelector('.aux');
all.addEventListener('click', allSel);
aux.addEventListener('click', addTask);

function toDo(event) {
  const parent = event.currentTarget;
  const clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked !== parent) {
    if (clicked.matches('.task')) {
      clicked.classList.toggle('selected');
    }
    if (clicked.matches('.status') || clicked.matches('.flag')) {
      clicked.classList.toggle('open');
      clicked.classList.toggle('done');
    }
    if (clicked.matches('.close')) {
      clicked.closest('.task').remove();
    }
  }
}

function allSel(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked.matches('#all')) {
    let marked = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
    marked.forEach(task => task.remove());
  }
}

function addTask(event) {
  const parent = event.currentTarget;
  const clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked !== parent) {
    if (clicked.matches('.flag')) {
      clicked.classList.toggle('open');
      clicked.classList.toggle('done');
    }

    if (clicked.matches('#add')) {
      const list = document.querySelector('#list');
      const text = clicked.previousElementSibling;
      const priority = text.previousElementSibling;
      const task = priority.matches('.done') ? [`
    <li class='task'><b class='flag open'></b>
    &nbsp;${text.value}&nbsp;
    <b class='status close'>❎</b></li>`, 'afterbegin'] : [`
    <li class='task'><b class='status open'></b>
    &nbsp;${text.value}&nbsp;
    <b class='status close'>❎</b></li>`, 'beforeend'];
      list.insertAdjacentHTML(task[1], task[0]);
      priority.classList.add('open');
      priority.classList.remove('done');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 400 4vh/1.5 Arial
}

.title {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
#all {
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

#all,
#all:link,
#all:visited {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: #999;
}

#all:hover,
#all:active {
  color: #000;
}

#list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

li,
b {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

li:hover,
li.selected {
  background: rgba(24, 228, 42, 0.3);
}

b {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open::before {
  content: ' '
}

.done::before {
  content: '✅ '
}

.close {
  float: right
}

.aux {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.aux .flag,
.aux input {
  display: table-cell;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.aux .flag {
  width: 5%;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.flag.open::before {
  content: ' ';
}

.flag.done::before {
  content: '\002611\00fe0f';
}

#text {
  width: 88%;
}

#add {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #16C60C;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <section class="row">
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Meet Denise</li>
      <li>Grocery</li>
      <li>Book Appointment</li>
      <li>Watch GOT</li>
      <li>Book Flight</li>
      <li>Buy Ipad</li>
      <li>Pick Up Kids</li>
      <li>Complete Homework</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks.This is going to be quite helpful.